# How to: Sync Dropbox to /mnt/raid5/Dropbox CentOS7

Tags: linux, centos, systemd, filesystems, dropbox

I managed to get dropbox installed on CentOS7 finally.

However, I need Dropbox to sync to `/mnt/raid5/Dropbox`. There is no option for me to select `/mnt/raid5Dropbox`.
I tried putting `/mnt/raid5/Dropbox` in the Directory field and pressed enter but got *"Directory not found"*

Any ideas here?

[image: Dropbox]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution was quite simple actually.  I removed the original Dropbox location with `rm -rf /home/orca/Dropbox` then made a sysmlink to the raid5 `ln -s /home/orca/Dropbox/mnt/raid5/Dropbox` and now 1TB of data is storing to where I want it too =)

Comment: Can you tell me If this solution is working for you without errors, now a couple of months have passed? I would like to symlink my new Dropbox business account ~/Dropbox (firm-name)/ to  ~/Dropbox/ in order to avoid the space in my filepaths and to preserve my absolute paths in scripts and so on. I'm unsure wether using a symlink like you're doing have unforeseen consequences.

Comment: Does not work. I am going have to download all the files manually.

Comment: Good to know. thanks for the response.

Comment: have you tried mount --bind? like this guy https://superuser.com/questions/1168532/how-do-i-change-the-dropbox-for-business-location-on-a-headless-linux-server

Comment: Yeah bro I tried it all. Spend lots of time on this. I’m getting rid off Dropbox and going with next cloud.

Comment: Damn. I asked the question here if in case you could still use it sometime. The guy who just  answered makes it seem like both symlink and mount should work fine, but one thing is in theory another is practice and with a big complicated folder. 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/643053/linking-a-dropbox-business-acccount-from-dropbox-firm-name-to-dropbox/

Comment: Dropbox ignored the solution I suggested fir their obsolete technology. Yeah I tried all the fancy bells and whistles with one of my ace apprentices and we couldn’t get it to work because of some variable on their end. Control. Dropbox is literally holding my files hostage same with Microsoft in another product. It’s so annoying.