# Linking a dropbox business acccount from “~/Dropbox (firm-name)” to “~/Dropbox”, with "mount --bind" or symlink or something else?

Tags: linux, symlink, bind-mount, dropbox

Been using my Dropbox account for years on a Lubuntu system. Now, my new company has made a Business account available to me.

However, Dropbox insists that this folder should be called:

```
~/Dropbox (firm-name)/
```

And there seems to be no way of changing it. I'm by no means a linux or cli expert, but one thing is renaming all my different absolute paths to something else, that's a one-time effort, but another thing is renaming it into something else *with spaces*. I'm foreseeing a lot of minor annoyance in my workflow if all filepaths I use suddenly includes a space by default.

So one possible way around this is to either symlink or mount --bind the   ~/Dropbox (firm-name)/ as
~/Dropbox/.

[This question seems to be concerning the same issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1168532/how-do-i-change-the-dropbox-for-business-location-on-a-headless-linux-server), and suggests using mount to bind the directory. by doing that, I would:

```
sudo mount --bind '~/Dropbox (firm-name)/' ~/Dropbox/
```

And then put it in /etc/fstab so it doesn't disappear when rebooting.

However, I'm basically unsure of wether that is a very bad idea that will lead to all sorts of issues. [I don't understand the mount command well enough](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount) to feel comfortable using it for something so important as this without guidance.

Symlinks in dropbox have worked fine for me when placing a symlink outside dropbox pointing to a file or folder in Dropbox, but symlinks inside the Dropbox folder has led to issues in the past, [that seems to have changed, however](http://www.paulingraham.com/dropbox-and-symlinks.html). This use-case is different, in the sense it is the entire dropbox folder that should be synced, like so:

```
ln -s '~/Dropbox (firm-name)' '~/Dropbox'
```

**So I'm asking: what -if any - is a safe, reliable way of linking ~/Dropbox (firm-name)/ to ~/Dropbox/?** It seems like a mount --bind or a symlink are the two best possibilites, but [even though I've read about the differences](https://askubuntu.com/questions/557733/what-is-the-difference-between-ln-s-and-mount-bind#:%7E:text=A%20symbolic%20link%20requires%20that%20the%20original%20be%20moved%20or%20deleted.&text=is%20not%20useful-,Show%20activity%20on%20this%20post.,a%20special%20type%20of%20file.), I don't know which of the two I should choose for this scenario. Is it even possible to do in a reliable way, or should I just pay up for my own account (seems so redundant though!). [the symlink-way seems to have worked for this guy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/616968/how-to-sync-dropbox-to-mnt-raid5-dropbox-centos7), but it's not a very detailed answer and I'm afraid of the unforeseen consequences and the loss of data and work.

*note:
It could be argued that the question I link to is the same question, but the original author never accepted the only answer. Also, there are some differences in his circumstances with a headless server, and being not an advanced user, although I've been using linux for years, I don't know if our premises are the same. I will argue less advanced users would benefit from a question and answer to this that had a very basic use-case premise.*

Comment: At the moment it doesn't answer your question, but I suggest you use the FOSS [Maestral](https://github.com/SamSchott/maestral) instead of the Dropbox official client. See [Maestral#347](https://github.com/SamSchott/maestral/issues/347) for your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ways are safe (personally, I prefer and use the bind mount alternative). There are a few minor differences, which may or may not be relevant to you:

- By default, file indexers (e.g. `updatedb`) tend to skip symbolic links and not to skip bind mounts. E.g. if `~/Dropbox` is a symlink, `locate a_file_in_Dropbox` would find the file in `~/Dropbox (firm-name)/` only; it will instead find the file in both `~/Dropbox (firm-name)/` and `~/Dropbox` if `~/Dropbox` is a mount point.
- Other programs may as well slightly change their behavior when operating on symlinks. A bind mount is more likely to ensure a seamless experience.
- In the bind mount case, failing to mount `~/Dropbox (firm-name)/` to `~/Dropbox` may cause processes to write files in the `~/Dropbox` directory (the mount point), and not, as intended, in `~/Dropbox (firm-name)/`. On the contrary, writing something in a broken symbolic link will just fail with an error.

My advice is to create the `/home/your_user/Dropbox` directory and add

```
/home/your_user/Dropbox\040(firm-name) /home/your_user/Dropbox none bind 0 0
```

to `/etc/fstab`. (It will be mounted on next boot or by running `sudo mount --all`).

Given that, in `fstab`, spaces and tabs are used to separate fields, literal spaces and tabs in mount points — and, where appropriate, as in the case of bind mounts, also in the first field — have to be replaced with the `\040` and `\011` escape sequences respectively.

---

Note that the tilde (which is not special as a *path*) is only [expanded](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01) by your shell if unquoted. The command:

```bsh
ln -s '~/Dropbox (firm-name)' '~/Dropbox'
```

tries to create a symbolic link named `Dropbox` in a directory (literally) named `~`, located in the current working directory (which is unlikely to exist, causing an error). And that link will point to a file named `Dropbox (firm-name)` locate inside that same `~` directory.
It should be:

```bsh
ln -s ~/'Dropbox (firm-name)' ~/Dropbox
```

Comment: I will try mounting, and see how it goes, and approve your answer as the right one if it works-  could take a little time, however, need to test it properly. thank you for the correction about the symlinks.

Comment: I just did it and will report back with results. Note however on a Lubuntu 20.04 machine you can't use  quotes in fstab and get the space understood properly as a space. You need to use  \40 instead like so:
/home/your_user/Dropbox\40(firm-name)
This is the exact reason why want to do this to begin with, to avoid all the bullsh*t with spaces :D
https://superuser.com/questions/527495/how-to-mount-partition-with-spaces-in-path

Comment: @emilBeBri Right, thanks. Answer fixed.

Comment: it is working without issues so far, in a dropbox with ~ 75 GB and symlinks pointing into the "mount bind" folder (though haven't tried the othe way around)

Comment: Symlinks placed outside a Dropbox directory and pointing to files (and directories) inside a Dropbox directory are safe. To minimize headaches, my advice is to just avoid symlinks placed inside a Dropbox directory, regardless of what they point to. Being designed to sync between incompatible operating systems, Dropbox can't easily preserve every kind of file (not just symlinks: think about FIFOs, block/character special files, sockets).

Comment: rIght, thanks, that's what I heard as well. Just wanted to make clear under which conditions it Is working flawlessly under.